# How can I query custom fields with the Fogbugz API?

Tags: fogbugz, fogbugz-api

I'm using the Python fogbugz module to access the XML API:

```
from fogbugz import FogBugz
fb = FogBugz(url=S_FOGBUGZ_URL, token=TOKEN)
respBug = fb.search(
    q=str(ixBug),
    cols="sTitle,sPersonAssignedTo,sProject,sArea,sCategory,sPriority,sStatus,events",
)
```

How can I add a custom field to the list of columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `customFields` as column name. The XML in the response is pretty messed up though, with weird tag names.

I found the answer by looking at the correspondence of the Firefox web client with the server.